# Convert CGI REMOTE_ADDR to network byte order for use with MySql INET_NTOA

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi, environment-variables, ip-address

I'm trying to log requests for a script and I want to store the client's IP Address in an `int(4)` column, using `INET_NTOA()` to return it in a readable function.

However, in my Perl CGI script, `$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}` contains an IP in host byte order which, when entered into the database with the `INET_ATON()` function, is converted incorrectly so when I pull it back out, I have a completely different address.

```
#!usr/bin/perl -wT

use strict; 
use CGI;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$server", "$user", "$password");
my $addr = $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR};

my $insert = $dbh->prepare(qq[insert into access_log (ipaddress) 
                                     values (INET_ATON('$addr'))]);  

$insert->execute or die "sql insert error";

my $retrieve = $dbh->prepare(qq[select INET_NTOA(ipaddress) as IP_Address 
                                from   access_log]);

$retrieve->execute or die "sql select error";
my $newIP = $retrieve->fetchrow_array;
```

Ideally, this script should return the value of `$addr` but instead I get something completely different. How can I format `$addr` before putting it into the database?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: TRWTF is that writing IPv4-only code in 2011. Rethink your choice of data storage for IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that no change to the $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} is needed.

By using a an int(4) unsigned for my ip_address column, inet_aton() and inet_ntoa() work correctly. With a signed integer,

"values corresponding to IP addresses for which the first octet is greater than 127 cannot be stored correctly" so the data gets distorted in the insert stage.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa

Answer (score 0):

Odd. The ENV var should be the normal dotted-quad notation, not a raw integer. Shouldn't it be `$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}` anyways?

Note that your INT column should be unsigned. inet_ntoa() does not like negative numbers, and half the IP address space will show up as negative if you store it in signed int fields.

Comment: It is normal dotted-quad notation but the INET_ATON() function in mysql converts it to an integer and that is how it's stored. As to your other question, it works without the single quotes. No idea if its bad practice to do it that way though.

Comment: @WillReese: Barewords can be used as hash keys.